# How to format CCM_UserAffinity output to tyoe Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalPrincipal

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I am trying to create a deployment script which adds freshly deployed workstation primary users to local admin group. I utilized CCM_userAffinity class to obtain username, however - Add-LocalGroupMember does not accept its output.

Ive tried creating task sequence variable to pass into powershell script which adds to group with no success either. Preferably the solution would be integrated within deployment TS, however due to no success i have reverted to ps package deployment.

```
$computer = "LocalHost" 
$namespace = "root\ccm\Policy\Machine" 
$query = "ConsoleUser"
$PrimaryUser = Get-WmiObject -class CCM_UserAffinity -computername $computer -namespace $namespace | select-object $query | format-wide
```

i expected the output from -class CCM_UserAffinity to be accepted by Add-LocalGroupMember, however i get this instead - 
Add-LocalGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Member'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" value of type 
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalPrincipal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you plan on using the value you retrieve and not displaying it there is no need to use something like "format-wide" which only makes the output human readable and is the reason for your FormatStartData datatype.

You can just use :

```
$PrimaryUser = (Get-WmiObject -class CCM_UserAffinity -computername $computer -namespace $namespace).ConsoleUser
```

which returns a string and that is taken by the -Member argument of Add-LocalGroupMember

One thing to keep in mind is that in theory there can be more than one ConsoleUser per machine. So the ConsoleUser might be an Array or not. If you can guarantee that there is always only one user in your environment per machine (at the point where the ts runs) you can just use it as is. Otherwise you would have to specify which user you want to use and I can of course not tell you what a good rule for that for your environment would be.

Also I hope you checked that the WMI class CCM_UserAffinity is already populated at the stage where you want to run this script, I could not tell you if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved the day and i will come back to give you a vote up when i have enough score. I didn't quite catch why you put the brackets in but ill try reading up on that.

Comment: The backets are roughly the same as in maths. They tell ps to first execute the gt-wmiobject cmdlet and take the consoleuser property from the result. It's the same as writing $temp = Get-WmiObject ... and then $PrimaryUser = $temp.ConsoleUser as the next line. I think you should be able to mark the answer as accepted (the check mark not the up arrow) without need for more points if you found it to solve your problem..

Comment: Thanks again, you have been great help!